# Apollo GraphQl model attribute is not accessing object in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am implementing category and subcategory display in ReactJs using Apollo GraphQl Query.

I tried to using same table as **category** with fields.
id,
category_name,
category_img,
category_parent_id ( id from same table),
category_status,

**typeDefs and resolver are belows**

**Category.js**

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Query {
    getSingleCategory(id: ID): allCategory
  }
`;
type allCategory {
    id: ID!
    category_name: String
    category_img: String
    category_parent_id: Int
    category_status: Status
 }

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
   getSingleCategory: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
   var data = await db.category.findOne({
     where: {
        id: args.id,
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: db.category,
          as: "children",
          attributes: [["category_name", "children_name"]],
          nested: true,
          required: false,
        },
      ],
      required: false,
    });
    return data;
 },
},
},
```

**Model in GraphQl**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var category = sequelize.define(
    "category",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      category_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      category_img: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      category_parent_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          // WorkingDays hasMany Users n:n
          model: "category",
          key: "children",
        },
      },
      category_status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM("Acitve", "Inactive"),
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: "category",
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
  category.associate = function (models) {
    models.category.belongsTo(models.category, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: "category_parent_id",
      as: "children",
      targetKey: "id",
    });
  };
  return category;
};
```

**In ReactJs**
**category.ts**

```
export const GET_CATEGORYBY_ID = gql`
  query($catId: ID!) {
    getSingleCategory(id: $catId) {
      id
      category_name
      category_img
      category_parent_id
      category_status
    }
  }
`;
```

I am trying to accessing {data.getSingleCategory} , **I got all parameters but not able to get children_name from same table as parent_name.**

Anyone can tell me what is the issue I am not able to access that children_name as attribute from same table Or there any other way so that we can access category/subcategory from same table and display it to reactjs template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not defined [separately] in types, not used/defined [as 'children' property?] in parent type, not requested in query ... simply filtered out from response.